# Using relativelayout to add controls side by side to take the whole width of the screen

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

```
Android Studio 0.5.1
```

Hello,

The screenshot I have put in a layout_width of 200dp. But not a good solution as this will be too much or too small on the screen size. I would like to fit both so that the seekbar will only take up as much room as need to fit the textview in at the end.
[image]

Is it possible to use relativelayout to have controls side by side where the seekbar will take just enough room without overlapping the control to the right of it (TextView)?

I would like the seekbar and textview to take the whole of the width together.

For the seekbar I have used match parent. However, this has pushed the textview out of sight.

I would like the seekbar to stop where the textview starts. I don't want to use dp on the layout_width as each device is different.

I don't want to switch to linear layout as I have other controls that are using this layout (not shown here).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbSensitivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="15"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSensitivityDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="15"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sbSensitivity"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope you understand what I mean?

Many thanks for any suggetions,

Comment: please show a screenshot of what you got, vs what you wish to have. it's hard to understand or imagine what you need without visuals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbSensitivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="15"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvSensitivityDisplay"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSensitivityDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="15"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, that work great. I didn't think it would work. As you added android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvSensitivityDisplay" in the Seekbar. But the tvSensitivityDisplay isn't declared until after. so the sbSensitivity wouldn't know it exists yet. I guess I am wrong to think that it worked like this. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="2">

  <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbSensitivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="15"
       android:layout_weight="1"        
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSensitivityDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
      android:layout_weight="1"       
       android:text="15"
     />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I always try and avoid the nested linear layouts as it consumes to much rendering everytime the layout is created which results in battery life.